From {figure} to {sidefigure}
I would like to create a command called sidefigure which mimics the classical figure command with an additional parameter called width. It should be used as follows:
\begin{sidefigure}{width}[ht]%
\centering%
\includegraphics{figname}%
\caption{text}%
\label{fig:label};
\end{sidefigure}

and should perform exactly as the code below
\begin{figure}[ht]%
\centering%
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},floatwidth=sidefil,capbesidewidth=width}}]{figure}[]{\caption{text}\label{fig:label}}%
{\mbox{}\hfill\includegraphics{figname}}
\end{figure}%

I was tempted to use a newenvironment but the expected input parameters are not appropriate here. I just got aware of the package sidecap but I do not think it achieves what is described above.
Below is a mwe:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
\centering%
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},floatwidth=sidefil,capbesidewidth=5cm}}]{figure}[]{\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a mauris nec nisi faucibus facilisis. Vivamus pharetra lacinia nisl vitae commodo. Etiam mauris mi, luctus sed nibh non, maximus venenatis purus.}\label{fig:label}}%
{\mbox{}\hfill\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}

A similar request for tables:
\begin{sidetable}{width}[ht]%
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
a& a \\
b & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{text}%
\label{tab:label};
\end{sidetable}

which should exactly perform as the code below:
\begin{figure}[ht]%
\centering%
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},floatwidth=sidefil,capbesidewidth=width}}]{table}[]{\caption{text}\label{tab:label}}%
{\mbox{}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
a& a \\
b & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{figure}%


please provide a complete example we can compile. \floatbox, \capbeside, \thisfloatsetup etc. are not standard latex commands. we can't know what that code does unless you tell us how they are defined.

you should not need somebody to prod you to provide an mwe at this point. you know what a question should look like. you know how to add an mwe. this has been pointed out to you before.

@cfr yes, agreed. Sorry about that. I wrongly thought the involved commands were conventional.

The following provides what you're after:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidefigure}{ m O{htbp} b }{%
}{%
  \begingroup
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{ O{\@empty} m }{%
    \gdef\@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCSoPT{##1}%
    \protected@xdef\@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCS{##2}%
  }%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{ o m }{%
    \IfValueTF{##1}
      {\gdef\@CaPTioNoPT{##1}}
      {\gdef\@CaPTioNoPT{##2}}%
    \protected@xdef\@CaPTioN{##2}%
  }%
  \global\let\@LaBeL\@empty
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{ m }{%
    \gdef\@LaBeL{##1}%
  }%
  #3% Set the body to \includegraphics[.]{..}, \caption[.]{..}, \label{..}
  \endgroup
  \begin{figure}[#2]
    % Expand \includegraphics, \caption and \label commands
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\def\noexpand\@@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCS{\noexpand\includegraphics[\@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCSoPT]{\@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCS}}}\x
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\def\noexpand\@@CaPTioN{\noexpand\caption[\@CaPTioNoPT]{\@CaPTioN}}}\x
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\def\noexpand\@@LaBeL{\noexpand\label{\@LaBeL}}}\x
    \centering
    \floatbox
      [{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},floatwidth=sidefil,capbesidewidth=#1}}]
      {figure}
      []
      {\@@CaPTioN\@@LaBeL}
      {\mbox{}\hfill\@@iNCLuDeGRaPHiCS}
  \end{figure}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{sidefigure}{0.3\linewidth}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Proin a mauris nec nisi faucibus facilisis. 
    Vivamus pharetra lacinia nisl vitae commodo. 
    Etiam mauris mi, luctus sed nibh non, maximus venenatis purus.}%
  \label{fig:label}
\end{sidefigure}

\end{document}

We define a new sidefigure environment that will capture two arguments (width and float options) and the body. The body is then processed once in order to extract the arguments of \includegraphics[.]{..}, \caption[.]{..} and \label{..}, which is then used afterwards in floatrow's required input.
A better option would be to define a command where you can specify the inputs using a key-value style.

If you wish to do the same with a sidetable environment that includes a tabular environment, it's easier capturing the content using regular expressions.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_env_body_text_tl
\seq_new:N \l_tabular_seq
\seq_new:N \l_caption_seq
\seq_new:N \l_label_seq

% To allow for passing a token list (tl) to the second argument of \regex_extract_once
% This supplies the variant \regex_extract_once:nVTF
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_once:nnN {nVN}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sidetable}{ m O{htbp} +b }{}{%
  \tl_set:Nn \l_env_body_text_tl { #3 } % Store environment body in tl
%  \tl_show:N \l_env_body_text_tl
  
  \seq_clear:N \l_label_seq % Clear label sequence
  % Retrieve \label{..} from body/tl
  \regex_extract_once:nVN
    { \c{label} \{ .* \} } % <search>: \label{..}
    { \l_env_body_text_tl } % <text>
    \l_label_seq % <stored result>
  % Remove \label{..} from body/tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
    { \c{label} \{ .* \} } % <search>: \label{..}
    { } % <replacement>
    \l_env_body_text_tl % <text>

  \seq_clear:N \l_caption_seq % Clear caption sequence
  % Retrieve \caption[.]{..} from body/tl
  \regex_extract_once:nVN
    { \c{caption} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} } % <search>: \caption[.]{..}
    { \l_env_body_text_tl } % <text>
    \l_caption_seq % <stored result>
  % Remove \caption[.]{..} from body/tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
    { \c{caption} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} } % <search>: \caption[ ]{  }
    { } % <replacement>
    \l_env_body_text_tl % <text>
    
  \seq_clear:N \l_tabular_seq % Clear tabular sequence
  % Retrieve \begin{tabular}[.]{..} ... \end{tabular} from body/tl
  \regex_extract_once:nVN
    { \c{begin} \{ tabular \} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} .* \c{end} \{ tabular \} } % <search>: \begin{tabular}[.]{..} ... \end{tabular}
    { \l_env_body_text_tl } % <text>
    \l_tabular_seq % <stored result>
  % Remove \begin{tabular}[.]{..} ... \end{tabular} from body/tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
    { \c{begin} \{ tabular \} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} .* \c{end} \{ tabular \} } % <search>: \begin{tabular}[.]{..} ... \end{tabular}
    { } % <replacement>
    \l_env_body_text_tl % <text>
    
  \begin{table}[#2]
    \centering
    \floatbox
      [{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},floatwidth=sidefil,capbesidewidth=#1}}]
      {table}
      []
      {\seq_item:Nn \l_caption_seq { 1 } % Set \caption
       \seq_item:Nn \l_label_seq { 1 }} % Set \label
      {\mbox{} \hfill \seq_item:Nn \l_tabular_seq { 1 } } % Set table
  \end{table}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{sidetable}{0.3\linewidth}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    a & b \\
    \hline
    c & d
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Proin a mauris nec nisi faucibus facilisis. 
    Vivamus pharetra lacinia nisl vitae commodo. 
    Etiam mauris mi, luctus sed nibh non, maximus venenatis purus.}%
  \label{tbl:label}
\end{sidetable}

\end{document}


yes, really great! Thank you! I am not sure to understand your last comment because I think that's what I want to avoid actually, at least for that specific request.

I just updated my question for "sidetable". I am experimenting on my side but I am not too sure how to capture the \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular} content. Thanks

@pluton: See the updated answer.

great! Thanks a lot!
